# Require expertise for approval

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, experts

When I click on the "review" tab, I'm asked to review questions I have no clue about.

Would it be possible to only present (or allow) approval or rejection votes on questions that are in a tag for which I have at least 500 rep or something?  Or maybe just questions I've got favorited?

Btw, this edit approval system is a GREAT IDEA. :)  Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words Andomar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some cases, yes, editing does require subject expertise. In others, it just takes a decent command of English. Your proposal would cause the system to have false negatives: not showing people some submissions that they are qualified to judge. The current system has the opposite problem, AKA false positives: people sometimes get stuck looking at questions and thinking "I don't know what to do with this one."

The current system gives users an out, by allowing them to leave proposals they aren't sure about for someone else to judge. That flexibility goes away with the "require expertise" plan. As a result, I favor maintaining the *status quo*.

Comment: Makes sense... maybe present the top 3 I have expertise in op top?

Comment: That could work. Poorly written questions in less popular tags need love too, though.

Answer (score 4):

I hear you, when I discussed this with Jeff he said this was "Micro Optimising".

From the 300 or so edits I reviewed there were a handful - a tiny tiny handful of edits I was unable to deal with. One such edit I remember clearly is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163151/custom-queryset-and-manager-without-breaking-dry/2163921#2163921). Being an OK Ruby developer I can deal with many of the Python edits, however this particular one had some Python syntax I was not familiar with. My call on this edit was, skip, let somebody else deal with it.

The interesting thing is that the vast majority of edits I approved were in tags I am not expert in, fixing phrasing, typos and code snippets has a universal quality. In general I find that having lots of experience on our sites is actually more important than being a tag expert, when it comes to approvals / rejections.

Comment: Who is this Jeff fellow? Does he think he runs the site or something?

Comment: I found I was uncomfortable approving or rejecting edits in another tag, I guess because I'm not part of that tag's ecosystem.  But yeah it's definitely micro optimising, I was thinking this is something that could be done when working on nearby code for some other reason.